# How to delete a function argument early?

Tags: python, python-2.7, destructor, reference-counting

I'm writing a function which takes a huge argument, and runs for a long time. It needs the argument only halfway. Is there a way for the function to delete the value pointed to by the argument if there are no more references to it?

I was able to get it deleted as soon as the function returns, like this:

```
def f(m):
  print 'S1'
  m = None
  #__import__('gc').collect()  # Uncommenting this doesn't help.
  print 'S2'
class M(object):   
  def __del__(self):
    print '__del__'
f(M())
```

This prints:

```
S1
S2
__del__
```

I need:

```
S1
__del__
S2
```

I was also trying `def f(*args):` and `def f(**kwargs)`, but it didn't help, I still get `__del__` last.

Please note that my code is relying on the fact that Python has reference counting, and `__del__` gets called as soon as an object's reference count drops to zero. I want the reference count of a function argument drop to zero in the middle of a function. Is this possible?

Please note that I know of a workaround: passing a list of arguments:

```
def f(ms):
  print 'S1'
  del ms[:]
  print 'S2'
class M(object):   
  def __del__(self):
    print '__del__'
f([M()])
```

This prints:

```
S1
__del__
S2
```

Is there a way to get the early deletion without changing the API (e.g. introducing lists to the arguments)?

If it's hard to get a portable solution which works in many Python implementations, I need something which works in the most recent CPython 2.7. It doesn't have to be documented.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Generally I think that python will not garbage collect something as soon as it's reference count hits 0, but only some (not defined) time after. You should be able to force a garbage collection.

Comment: The argument is being passed in from the caller's scope. Ultimately the object is still referenced there. However low you drop the ref count within your function, until your function ends the object probably won't be garbage collected because the parent's scope's references aren't cleaned up yet. – That's largely just a guess though, I don't know how the behaviour would differ between `foo(m)` and `foo(M())`; logic dictates it *shouldn't* differ, but that's also implementation dependent.

Comment: I *want* to say that even if you unbind the argument it still exists outside the function scope.

Comment: In the end you shouldn't depend on Python's internals for memory management. The best you can do to minimise memory consumption is to approach the problem differently and implement it in a way that is *guaranteed* to use less memory; e.g. by reading from a stream from disk or such.

Comment: @syntonym: I don't care about garbage collection. I'd like to know how I can make the reference count of the argument to drop to 0 early, so the object will be deleted.

Comment: You can never know when or count on `__del__()` being called, unless you do it explicitly yourself. Python is not C++.

Comment: @chepner: I know this. That's why I'm passing an anonymous object in the example. It still doesn't get deleted early enough, because the function call is holding a reference to it.

Comment: @martineau: I'm looking for a solution which works in CPython 2.7. Maybe the documentation of Python is vague about when `__del__` will be called, but for this question let's focus on how CPython 2.7 actually behaves (not how it is documented).

Comment: I'm talking about CPython. Went through the same learning curve when I first started working with Python after many years of coding in C++.

Comment: @deceze: I know how I can refactor my program so that it depends less on on the Python memory management internals than the examples above. But here I'm looking for a solution of a very specific problem. I understand that there is no portable, recommended and documented solution. But I'm looking for any solution now.

Comment: You could try passing a value-producing function into `f`, instead of the value itself. That allows `f` to control when (and if) that value is actually created, and makes `f` the sole 'owner' of that value.

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet: Thank you for the suggestion! It's a nice and useful pattern, but it doesn't help me. In the 2nd example in the question I'm already doing something similar when passing the `M` object in a list. And I'm asking if it's possible to avoid the extra indirection of the list, thus avoiding changing the API. Adding a different kind of indirection (e.g. function instead of a list) wouldn't solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like it's not possible to do the early deletion in CPython 2.7 without changing the API of the `f` function.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> CPython implementation detail: CPython currently uses a reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they become unreachable, but is not guaranteed to collect garbage containing circular references. See the documentation of the gc module for information on controlling the collection of cyclic garbage. Other implementations act differently and CPython may change. **Do not depend on immediate finalization of objects when they become unreachable** (ex: always close files).

Short of modifying the interpreter yourself, you *cannot* achieve what you want. `__del__` will be called when the interpreter decides to do it.

Comment: Or you call it yourself. Even then, the memory may not be reclaimed immediately, if ever.

Comment: Thank you for the quote. It proves that there is no documented and future-proof way to do it in CPython. I've clarified the question: I'd accept even an undocumented solution which works in CPython 2.7.

Comment: @martineau: Calling `m.__del__()` manually doesn't help me. I don't need `__del__` being called, I'm just using `__del__` as an indicator that the Python interpreter wants to delete the object. I care about the object being deleted early.

Comment: You can run the garbage collector manually with `gc.collect()`, but that will collect *everything* pending, not just your one object, which maybe will take longer than you want.

Comment: @chepner: Running `gc.collect()` after `m = None` doesn't help, the object still doesn't get deleted until the function returns.