# Does itertools.chain() allow memory to be released from consumed items

Tags: python, memory, iteration, python-itertools

I'm trying to reduce memory usage in a Django app by running a large query in batches. Even though I thought I was being clever, memory usage kept growing until eventually the process got killed. I currently have a theory that the querysets aren't being garbage collected, and I'm wondering if it has something to do with how I'm batching the queries.

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def get_data(pks):
    groups = list(grouper(pks, batch_size))
    querysets = [_queryset(pks) for pks in groups]
    return itertools.chain(*querysets)

for item in get_data([..big list of primary keys..]):
    process(item)
```

Let's say 3 querysets are generated in the `get_data` function. When I've consumed all items from the first queryset, will that queryset then be released? Or have I still technically got a reference to it from the chain?

I'm not certain the memory is being held here (it could be a database driver, something internal within Django itself, etc), but it seems like a decent candidate. Are there any good tools for measuring memory use by object type? This particular code is running on Python 2 (for now).

I should note I'm running this from an ipython shell, just incase that matters.

Edit:

It looks like `chain` isn't responsible here. I added some code to print out object counts per class, and the count of Model objects remain at a constant number.

```
import gc

def get_object_counts():
    from collections import Counter
    classes = []
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if hasattr(obj, '__class__'):
            classes.append(str(obj.__class__))
    return Counter(classes)
```

Then at specific intervals (batch size):

```
print(get_object_counts().most_common(30))
```

For completion sake, here's the top 9. I believe the major culprit is `django.db.models.base.ModelState`, which keeps growing and not getting collected.

First:

```
("<type 'dict'>", 59184)
("<type 'list'>", 48710)
("<type 'function'>", 48300)
("<type 'tuple'>", 38920)
("<type 'cell'>", 10203)
("<type 'weakref'>", 9957)
("<type 'set'>", 7230)
("<type 'type'>", 5947)
("<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelState'>", 4682)
```

Second:

```
("<type 'dict'>", 59238)
("<type 'list'>", 48730)
("<type 'function'>", 48315)
("<type 'tuple'>", 38937)
("<type 'cell'>", 10207)
("<type 'weakref'>", 9959)
("<type 'set'>", 7230)
("<type 'type'>", 5950)
("<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelState'>", 4696)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was seeing similar behavior myself and it appears that `itertools.chain` (and `itertools.chain.from_iterable`) retain references to anything passed as an argument until they have stopped iterating.  I expect this is why your django querysets, along with their cached results, are not being garbage collected.  This appears to be the behavior on both python2 and python3, and is also the behavior you see from any user-defined python function (see [How to delete a function argument early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505862/how-to-delete-a-function-argument-early)).  Perhaps functions in a C-language library such as itertools might have more freedom to delete references to arguments before they exit, but apparently they do not choose to do so.

As a workaround, you can wrap the individual arguments to `itertools.chain` in iterators by using `iter` or `itertools.chain` itself.  It appears that once these individual iterators are exhausted they drop their reference to their underlying iterable and allow it to be garbage collected.

One final note is that even completely consuming the results is not sufficient to release the memory -- control must be returned again to the iterator (or any sub-iterator in the chain) before the memory used by that iterator (or sub-iterator) is released.  Again, this is what you might expect from a normal python function.

The code below shows this all happening:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools
import gc

def print_whats_left_after(num, numbers_iter):
    """ Read three numbers and print what pairs haven't been gc'd """
    for _ in range(num):
        next(numbers_iter, None)
    gc.collect()
    # Print integer pairs that were not garbage collected
    print(sorted([o for o in gc.get_objects()
                  if isinstance(o, list) and len(o) == 2 and
                  all(isinstance(i, int) for i in o)]))

print_whats_left_after(2, itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(3, itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(4, itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(5, itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4]))
# -> []

print_whats_left_after(2, itertools.chain.from_iterable([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(3, itertools.chain.from_iterable([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

print_whats_left_after(2, itertools.chain(itertools.chain([1, 2]), [3, 4]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(3, itertools.chain(itertools.chain([1, 2]), [3, 4]))
# -> [[3, 4]]  # [1, 2] was gc'd!!!

print_whats_left_after(2, itertools.chain(iter([1, 2]), [3, 4]))
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(3, itertools.chain(iter([1, 2]), [3, 4]))
# -> [[3, 4]]  # [1, 2] was gc'd!!!
print_whats_left_after(4, itertools.chain(iter([1, 2]), [3, 4]))
# -> [[3, 4]]
print_whats_left_after(5, itertools.chain(iter([1, 2]), [3, 4]))
# -> []

def arg_clobberer(arg):
    arg = None
    yield
print_whats_left_after(0, arg_clobberer([1, 2]))
# -> [[1, 2]]
print_whats_left_after(1, arg_clobberer([1, 2]))
# -> []

def arg_deleter(arg):
    del arg
    yield
print_whats_left_after(0, arg_deleter([1, 2]))
# -> [[1, 2]]
print_whats_left_after(1, arg_deleter([1, 2]))
# -> []
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful information. Nice trick wrapping the arguments to chain in other generators. I ended up refactoring the original code so I can't actually test it, but I think you've sufficiently answered the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you could avoid creating temp lists (and fix the allocation problem at the source) by converting them to iterables/generators:

```
def get_data(pks):
    groups = grouper(pks, batch_size)  # turn off explicit list conversion
    querysets = (_queryset(pks) for pks in groups)  # gencomp not listcomp
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(querysets)  # nicer with "from_iterable"
```

Comment: The `grouper` function is taken from the itertools recipes doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes Isn't the listcomp with range the same as [] * n?

Comment: for immutable objects yes, but my construct generates one different iterable per element. Maybe I'm wrong, specially if it's code from recipes. Bar that for the moment.